# Pass value in TextField to other view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I have simple code with a TextField and just print the textfield in the same view.

I want to pass typed text to another View. It's not working currently and I don't know why.

Here is my first view code:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct Test: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField(
            "Your name",
            text: $username
        )
        
        Text("hello, \(username)")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        
        NavigationLink(destination: OtherView()){
            
            Text("GO TO OTHER VIEW")
                .frame(width: 280, height: 70)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my other view.

```
struct OtherView : View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack {  
            Text("hello, \(username)!")
                 .foregroundColor(.white)
                 .font(.headline)
                 .padding(30)
        }
    }
}
```

I doń't have any idea how can I make it possible to print typed text in other view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you have two completely separate `username` variables. One is owned by `Test` and the other is owned by `OtherView` -- they have no connection to each other (giving them the same name does not make them the same).

If you want to pass the value from the first `View` to the second, you can make it a *parameter* that gets passed into the second `View`.

That parameter doesn't need to be `@State` on the second `View`, since it's not mutated at all.

```
struct Test: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Your name", text: $username)
                Text("hello, \(username)")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                NavigationLink(destination: OtherView(username: username)){
                    Text("GO TO OTHER VIEW")
                }
            }
        }
        
    
    }
}

struct OtherView : View {
    var username: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hello, \(username)!")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've included what's necessary to create a minimal reproducible example, like having a `NavigationView` that you may not need in your original project if there's additional context there not included in the question.